# While loop in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to create a jmeter test in which I am taking the http requests and their bodies from the csv file.
I want to run it for 2 users which will fire the http requests mentioned in the csv file 2 times. Which means 2 users will simultaneously start the test, they will fire the http requests mentioned in the csv file once and then will do the same with 2nd iteration. I tried doing it with different settings for Recycle EOF to TRUE/FALSE and Stop thread on EOF to TRUE/FALSE but either it is going in infinite loop or it is firing the requests as . I am definitely missing something here. Any help is appreciated. I am using Jmeter version 5.3

[image: While loop]
[image: CSV file]
[image: http request pulling from csv file]
[image: csv file]

[image: Thread group]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest would be just replacing your While Controller with the [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) with the number of loops equal to the number of lines in the CSV file.

You can determine the number of lines using the following [__groovy() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/):

```
${__groovy(new File('c:/full.csv').readLines().size(),)}
```

[image]

In the CSV Data Set Config set "Recycle on EOF" and "Stop thread on EOF" to `false`

Comment: Thanks @DmitriT  :)  I tried using the groovy function.However, it did not read the csv file at all. logs on console. "WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor$1 (file:/C:/apache-jmeter-5.1.1_New/lib/groovy-all-2.4.16.jar) to constructor java.io.File(java.lang.String,java.io.File)
"Any idea what changes do I need to make in the groovy function to make it work and count the no of lines in csv file?